# React AWS S3 Upload: Tracking Progress Not Working

Tags: reactjs, upload

I am working on a React app where I use the `'react-aws-s3`' library to upload files to `AWS S3`. I'm trying to track the upload progress and display it to the user, but the progress isn't being shown as expected. Despite successful uploads, the console.log for progress isn't displaying either.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import LinearProgress from '@mui/material/LinearProgress';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { awsUpload } from './aws-upload';

const BasicUploader = () => {
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

    const handleFileChange = (event: any) => {
        setFile(event.target.files[0]);
    };

    const handleUpload = async () => {
        if (file) {
            try {
                const uploadedFile = await awsUpload({
                    file,
                    fileName: 'file_name',
                     dirName: `my_files/content/`,
                    onProgress: (loaded: any, total: any) => {
                        const uploadProgress = (loaded / total) * 100;
                         console.log('PROGRESS___', uploadProgress);
                        setProgress(uploadProgress);
                    },
                });
                console.log('File uploaded:', uploadedFile);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="file" accept="video/*" onChange={handleFileChange} />
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleUpload}>
                Upload
            </Button>
            {progress > 0 && (
                <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={progress} />
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default BasicUploader;
```

Aws-Upload hook

```
import S3 from 'react-aws-s3';
import { awsconfig } from './config/aws';

export const awsUpload = async ({
    file,
    fileName,
    dirName,
    onProgress,
}: any) => {
    try {
        const ReactS3Client = new S3(awsconfig);
        return await ReactS3Client.uploadFile(file, fileName, {
            onProgress: (progress: any) => {
                if (onProgress) {
                    console.log("PROGRESS:", {progress});
                    onProgress(progress.loaded, progress.total);
                }
            },
        });
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error('Error Occured while uploading');
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you see in console? Do you see the real-time update of the progress value?

Comment: @technophyle I don't see anything, the only console I see is console.log('File uploaded:', uploadedFile);

Comment: Ok, so that means your `onProgress` callback is not working.

Comment: @technophyle Yeah, It seems not to be working, Please any workaround or solution to achieve the progress functionlity with my upload

Comment: There's no mention on the callback in that package's README so you might need to use a different package.